# When does pandas output a series vs a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on the pandas tutorial at https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pycon-pandas-tutorial/blob/master/Exercises-3.ipynb. It has exercises on the `cast` dataframe, a sample of which is

[image]

There are two commands which are almost similar, except for one small difference, and one outputs a Series while the other outputs a dataframe. I don't understand why.

The first code is:

```
c1 = cast[cast.title == 'The Pink Panther']
c2 = c1.groupby('year')['n'].max()
type(c2)
```

and it makes c2 a Series. However, if I simply add another square brackets around 'n' as in the following code, I get a dataframe.

```
c1 = cast[cast.title == 'The Pink Panther']
c2 = c1.groupby('year')[['n']].max()
type(c2)
```

Can someone help me explain this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a list of columns, you get a DataFrame.  It doesn't matter how many elements the list has.  It would be confusing if it returned a Series just in the case of a one-item list, because sometimes your list might be programmatically generated.  For instance, suppose you had:

```
columns_to_use = [column for blah in blahblah]
x = c1.groupby('year')[columns_to_use]
```

With the current behavior, you know that `x` will always be a DataFrame, because `columns_to_use` is a list.  If this were not the case, you might get errors later because you wouldn't know ahead of time whether `x` would be a Series or DataFrame, so you wouldn't know, e.g., what methods you could call on it in later code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, If you pass `__getitem__` on a DataFrame a `Series`, `np.ndarray`, `Index`, or `list`, then you will get back an array (`DataFrame`).

Otherwise `__getitem__` will attempt to retrieve a a column (`Series`). This case includes stringtypes, numbers, a custom class, etc.

`DataFrameGroupBy` behaves similarly to `DataFrame` in that if a you pass any of the former listed objects(plus tuples apparently), you will get a two-dimensonal object back(DataFrame), otherwise it will attempt to retrieve a one-dimensional object(Series)

In your first code block you are passing a string:

```
>>> type(c1['year'])
pandas.core.frame.Series
```

In the second code block you pass a list containing a string to `__getitem__`

```
>>> type(c1[['year']])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

`[]` has multiple meanings in this case.

Passing a list of one element is generally not very useful however except for nicely printing the column name at the top (but the Series still retains the name of the column in the `name` attribute). The primary intent of passing a list to `__getitem__` is to key on multiple columns.

To see how brackets `[]` work on a class, check its `__getitem__` method.

From `pandas.series.core.frame.DataFrame`:

```
    if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
        # either boolean or fancy integer index
        return self._getitem_array(key)
    elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
        return self._getitem_frame(key)
    elif is_mi_columns:
        return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
    else:
        return self._getitem_column(key)
```